# R Machine Learning in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, rstudio, powerbi-desktop

What is the best way to create and run machine learning prediction code (with a training set and predictions) so that you can see the output (predictions) in PowerBI?

Comment: I would use Azure ML or Azure Databricks to do this, you can use the Dataflows ML https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-machine-learning-automated

Comment: You can write scripts in R and Python to predict data and use it as an input to PowerBI. Just use as input data in PowerBI your scripts to train model and produce an output.